# Storing metadata in PostgreSQL?

Tags: shapefile, postgresql, metadata

I am creating a database model with several table storing data from a data producer.
They produce their data with ArcGIS/QGIS and so produce an .xml file compliant ISO 19139.

We now want to store this data in a PostgreSQL Database and we would like to have the metadata in this system.

As far as I understand it, I would like to create a "metadata" schema (or table ?)
and store in an XML field format the content of the .xml file along with the name of the table, and then use it in the next part of the workflow.

Is there any guide about handling metadata in PostgreSQL ? 
I looked around and didn't find a clear answer for me.

I already saw this post : [Editing metadata in PostGIS database?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288943/editing-metadata-in-postgis-database)

Answer (score 1):

For what it sounds like you want to do, you could just use [GeoNetwork](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/), with PostgreSQL as the back end database.

Comment: So, you think it's not useful to re-store the metadata in the database ? I don't really know what is the best practice here ...

Comment: `So, you think it's not useful to re-store the metadata in the database ?`  I didn't say that, rather you have in your Q `store in an XML field format the content of the .xml file along `  If you just want to store the contents of the XML file in one field in a database then you get this out of the box with GeoNetwork.  So you don't need to design it yourself. plus you get a GUI front end, plus you can  export in a number of formats...

Comment: yes, if I use GeonetWork afterward, I don't have to do anything to the raw file and we will have a good use of it. I will dig in this way to see if it may fill the need. thanks for the pointer !