# How to store metadata in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, metadata

How can I include metadata for my data in PostGIS? I want to have the associated metadata for my shapefiles saved alongside the data in my database so that I can connect the database to QGIS and display the data there.

Comment: Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288943/editing-metadata-in-postgis-database help?

Comment: I'm unable to save those edits to the database, any tips on how to deal with this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.